# Website not accessible externally following PHP upgrade

Tags: apache, networking, centos, php-7.2

Bit of a strange one - Over the weekend I updated the version of PHP on one of our servers and all seemed to be working fine, however yesterday, we started to receive complaints that the site was down.

After looking in to it, the site works fine when connecting from the internal network, but it times out when trying to connect from an external IP address.

Server admin isn't really my strong suit, so not really sure where to begin. I've checked the httpd.conf files and all looks fine, the apache config test reutrns 'OK' so at a loss as to where to go next.

Server is running Centos, PHP 7.2 and apache 2.4.6.

How can I get the server to respond to external requests?

Andy

Answer (score 1):

You can use this tools (metod) to check where is propably the problem:

I. on serwer, check :

1. whether is serwer conections to internet - ping, tracerout
2. whether page is loading (on local)  - lynks, links (text web broweser)
3. whether your dns is working (or dns ISP prowider) - depending on the service used, e.g. BIND (check usage this tool in internet)
4. whether your firewall is ok configured and good work -  depending on the service used e.g. iptables
5. whether domen settings is ok,
6. ...

II. on computer, check: (in internet, not in local network with your serwer)

1. whether the website loads in the browser eg firefox after using ip address (your server where the page is located) in www bar
2. whether host in internet have a contact with your serwer - ping, tracerout
3. whether the website loads in the browser eg firefox after using ip address (your server where the page is located) in www bar
4. ...

The problem is wery complicadet becouse I dont now what exactly you have an infrastructure and it is settings (network, ISP, etc.) which you on host the page you are writing about. For this reason, it is difficult for you to precisely help.